# Extract component from jar or reuse exported jar

Tags: talend

Can someone help me to open this job (or driver) on talend please?
if i can only extract the component named : tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1
it gona be cool for me...
Thank you in advance

Driver here :   https://easyupload.io/5iwqpm

Comment: Did you try adding your jars in window>preferences>Java>Build path
And then use you classes in java components ? is that wath you are searching for ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  this is not a question

Answer (score 0):

Do you think if i add some external jars in the build path, i will see new components there ?